# Can not sign in using ASP.NET Identity, Value cannot be null.Parameter name: manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've this login method when I reach at this point it gives me an error

```
var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(userName, password, false, false);
```

The exception it shows is this

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

But here is the main error that it shows

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: manager"}

here is the stack trace

```
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManagerExtensions.PasswordSignIn[TUser,TKey](SignInManager`2 manager, String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean shouldLockout)
   at MIS.Web.Controllers.PublicController.ValidateUser(String userName, String password) in C:\Users\Jack\Dropbox\Angular 2 Test Environment\MIS BackUp\MIS.Web\MIS.Web\Controllers\PublicController.cs:line 138
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

This here is my complete login method

```
 public string ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            userStore.Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
            var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);


            var user = manager.Find(userName, password);
            manager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);



            var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(userName, password, false, false);
            if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
                return userName;

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I guess UserManager is not registered in your owin context . Make sure you have app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create); in your startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the user I created before extending my `OWIN` to `role` based and `group` based `Authorization` became null and void so I'd to add this new line every time I create a new user its `SecurtyStamp` needed to be updated like this

```
await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
```

Hope this helps any one

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that Id and UserName is not null or empty!